# Pulling Regex Output Array from Inside Another Array

Tags: php, regex

So I'm trying to pull phone numbers from a text file, each line of the text file represents one user profile. So the code I have so far opens the text file, separates each line via an array, then uses a regex to find the phone numbers. My question is how to do I break the regex results so I can store each number into a variable? So far my code just shows me the second array I need something like a second foreach as each line of user data could contain between 1 and 6 phone numbers.

```
 <?php
        $array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('data\samdata_000030.txt'));
        foreach ($array as $string){
        echo $string."<br><br><br>";
        preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{4}\b/',$string,$matches);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($matches[0]);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Comment: simply nest a second `foreach` into the outer one. What's your end goal?. So, do you want six variables created if 6 phone numbers are found in one line?

Comment: Yeah that would be correct, when I nest another foreach I just get a bunch of errors. Let me try it and post the code up so you can see.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for adding the second foreach and displaying the data correctly..

```
foreach($matches[0] as $matched) {
        echo $matched;
}
```